# Website Host Gone | Recover the old website

Tags: hosting, httrack

my client lost his webiste hosting cause he didn't pay the last 3 months, so the host deleted the webiste on their servers.
Now we have a version on https://web.archive.org ,
How we can recover it , and upload it agian on an other host server.

Please Help guys

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use this 
https://websitedownloader.io/wayback-machine-downloader/

But you can download only the front-end and there is no way recover back-end code, you should develop it again, or you can ask hosting provider a recover image for extra payment, some hostings do that

Comment: Thanks Pavel Beresnev 
I tried with httrack but still can't recover all the website.
Okey I'll find one 
Thanks :)